# What can Spring Boot Application classes extend?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I notice that Spring Boot application classes can extend other classes, but that the `main(String[] args)` methods generally all use `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)`.  The examples often use different annotations above the `Application` class definition.

This OP asks for a simple summary of three closely related questions:

1.) What are the possible classes that a Spring Boot Application.java class can extend?

2.) What are the intended uses of each of the extension options?

3.) And does the choice of a given extension also dictate specific annotations that must be added to the class definition?

From my research, I have identified the following three extension options:

1.) Extend nothing at all, as per this example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

2.) Extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, as per this example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class UiApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

3.) Extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`, as per this example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.default", System.getProperty("spring.profiles.default", "dev"));
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Notice that I kept the annotations and minimal other stuff from the examples.  This OP asks simply if specific annotation choices or minimal other stuff are dictated by the choice of extension.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of all these classes? Because they most probably answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Another one, which is not inheritance but it's composition, is to implement the CommandLineRunner interface so that you can perform some operations when the Spring Boot application starts up, like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DevopsbuddyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

/** The application logger */
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DevopsbuddyApplication.class);

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Value("${webmaster.username}")
private String webmasterUsername;

@Value("${webmaster.password}")
private String webmasterPassword;

@Value("${webmaster.email}")
private String webmasterEmail;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DevopsbuddyApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    User user = UserUtils.createBasicUser(webmasterUsername, webmasterEmail);
    user.setPassword(webmasterPassword);
    Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
    userRoles.add(new UserRole(user, new Role(RolesEnum.ADMIN)));
    LOG.debug("Creating user with username {}", user.getUsername());
    userService.createUser(user, PlansEnum.PRO, userRoles);
    LOG.info("User {} created", user.getUsername());
}
}
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for though.